# Getting a mysterious FROM clause syntax error

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, ms-access

I'm trying to get a label to display how many entries exist in a database. And I'm using the most ridiculously simple FROM I can imagine. And I'm getting spammed with "Syntax error in FROM clause" rather than having my label update. Syntax is an error I get a lot when I use a system reserved name for a table or column. But the table name I'm using works in other statements, so I assume that's not the issue, and it's the ONLY variable. Unless it's something other than the FROM and it's lying to me, which is entirely possible...

```
        if (DateTime.Now.Millisecond > 500)
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=access.mdb";
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM probe)", conn);
                using (OleDbDataReader myReader = cmmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(myReader);
                    int count = dt.Rows.Count;
                    lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException expe)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(expe.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have an extra closing parenthesis in your select statement. Did you LOOK at your `FROM` clause to see if there was a syntax error? :p

Comment: I looked. the problem was SEEING, hah. I'm just not experienced enough with the command to recognize the problem, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM probe)
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM probe
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM probe)", conn);
```

to

```
OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM probe", conn);
```